# HTML5 DVR not working -- SourceBuffer removed from parent element

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, mediarecorder, media-source

### Goal

I'm attempting to create a rudimentary "DVR" for an HTML5 video element by utilizing `MediaRecorder`, `MediaSource`, and `SourceBuffer`. At the moment this is just a proof of concept. However since many projects like HLS.js take advantage of the HTML5 video element, I believe this would have wide-spread value.

### Code

Here's the gist of my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="src-video" src="http://localhost:8080/video/source.mp4" autoplay></video>
    <video id="dvr-video"></video>
    <input id="seekbar" type="range" min="-120" max="0" value="0" />
    <script>
    var mr; // MediaRecorder
    var ms = new MediaSource();
    var srcBuf; // SourceBuffer
    var srcUrl = URL.createObjectURL(ms);
    var srcVid = document.getElementById("src-video");
    var dvrVid = document.getElementById("dvr-video");
    var dvrData = []; // array of ArrayBuffer
    var queue = [];

    ms.addEventListener("sourceopen", sourceOpen);
    srcVid.addEventListener("playing", setupMediaRecorder);
    dvrVid.src = srcUrl;

    var seekBar = document.getElementById("seekbar");
    seekBar.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        // Destroy the old media source and make a new one
        URL.revokeObjectURL(srcUrl);
        srcBuf = null;

        ms = new MediaSource();
        ms.addEventListener("sourceopen", sourceOpen);
        srcUrl = URL.createObjectURL(ms);

        body.removeChild(dvr);
        dvr = document.createElement("video");
        body.insertBefore(dvr, seekBar);

        dvr.src = srcUrl;
    });

    function sourceOpen()
    {
        // Create the source buffer
        if (!srcBuf)
        {
            srcBuf = src.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="opus,vp8"');
            srcBuf.mode = "sequence";
        }

        srcBuf.addEventListener('updateend', function() {
            if ( queue.length ) {
                srcBuf.appendBuffer(queue.shift());
            } else {
                dvr.play();
            }
        }, false);

        // Add all fragments in cache
        var start = dvrData.length + parseInt(seekBar.value);
        queue = [];
        for( var i = start; i < dvrData.length; i++ )
        {
            if (dvrData[i])
                queue.push(dvrData[i]);
        }
        if (queue.length)
            srcBuf.appendBuffer(queue.shift());
    }

    function setupMediaRecorder()
    {
        var stream = srcVid.captureStream()
        mr = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        mr.ondataavailable = function(e) {
            // Convert the Blob to an ArrayBuffer
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function() {
                // Append this ArrayBuffer to our playing video
                if (srcBuf)
                {
                    if (srcBuf.updating || queue.length)
                        queue.push(this.result);
                    else
                        srcBuf.appendBuffer(this.result);
                }
                // And to our historical array (for seeking purposes)
                dvrData.push(this.result);
                if (dvrData.length > 120) {
                    // Keep only 2 minutes of data
                    dvrData.splice(0, 1);
                }
            };
            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.data);
        };
        mr.start();
        // Record 1-second chunks
        setInterval(function() {
            mr.requestData();
        }, 1000);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Result

When the page first loads, the "live" video element begins to play, and 1 second later the "dvr" element begins to play - with a 1-second delay. So it seems to be working at first.

The moment I perform a seek, the dvr element goes black and I get the following error in the console (line number may not match exactly with code above):

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source.
at SourceBuffer.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/video/dvr.html:80:13)
```

Looking at `chrome://media-internals` for further details, I see the following for the DVR player:

```
+-------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Timestamp   | Property       | Value
+-------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 00:00:00 00 | origin_url     | http://localhost:8080/
| 00:00:00 00 | frame_url      | http://localhost:8080/video/dvr.html
| 00:00:00 00 | frame_title    |
| 00:00:00 00 | url            | blob:http://localhost:8080/cec4134a-4498-43c5-8321-3743761636ac
| 00:00:00 00 | info           | ChunkDemuxer: buffering by DTS
| 00:00:00 00 | pipeline_state | kStarting
| 00:00:00 03 | error          | Unexpected element ID 0xa3
| 00:00:00 03 | error          | Append: stream parsing failed. Data size=112300 append_window_start=0 append_window_end=inf
| 00:00:00 08 | pipeline_error | CHUNK_DEMUXER_ERROR_APPEND_FAILED
| 00:00:00 10 | pipeline_state | kStopping
| 00:00:00 10 | pipeline_state | kStopped
+-------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `Unexpected element ID 0xa3` seems to be the culprit. Although for some reason this error wasn't thrown when the page first loaded (I'm appending the same `ArrayBuffer`s to my `SourceBuffer`, so if they didn't throw this error before I don't know why they're throwing it now)

Looking up `0xa3` with respect to the WEBM format, it sounds like this refers to a "SimpleBlock" -- https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libwebm/+/libwebm-1.0.0.26/webmids.hpp -- I don't know why this would throw an error?

### Things I've tried

- Since it takes a moment for the initial video to start playing, I thought there may be a race condition in setting up the MediaSource. I added a 1-second delay after seeking before creating the new MediaSource, SourceBuffer, etc. This did not help
- I thought there may be errors if the first chunk loaded didn't contain a keyframe, so I increased the chunk size from 1 second to 10 seconds
- I've tried various source files (MKV, MOV, MP4, RTMP stream, WebRTC stream, etc)
- I've tried destroying the entire `video` element and re-creating it
- In case the `SourceBuffer` is somehow modifying the `ArrayBuffer`s when they're played, I tried appending copies instead of the original objects (`srcBuf.appendBuffer(queue.shift().slice(0));`)
- I've tried switching between `segment` and `sequence` modes on the `SourceBuffer`
- In case the DVR element was playing the instant I created a `SourceBuffer` (before I had data) and entering a "media complete" state, I tried pausing the DVR element

So far I haven't had any luck getting DVR to work correctly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I've got it

After a lot more experimentation I finally figured out the issue.

WEBM files are effectively binary-encoded XML files. The schema looks something like this:

```
<EBML>
    <EBMLVersion>...</EBMLVersion>
    <EBMLReadVersion>...</EBMLReadVersion>
    <EBMLMaxIDLength>...</EBMLMaxIDLength>
    <EBMLMaxSizeLength>...</EMBLMaxSizeLength>
    <DocType>...</DocType>
    <DocTypeVersion>...</DocTypeVersion>
    <DocTypeReadVersion>...</DocTypeReadVersion>
</EBML>
<Segment>
    <SeekHead>
        <Seek>...</Seek>
        <Seek>...</Seek>
        <Seek>...</Seek>
    </SeekHead>
    <Void></Void>
    <Info>...</Info>
    <Tracks>
        <TrackEntry>
            <Video>
                <Colour>
                    <MatrixCoeffciient>...</MatrixCoefficients>
                    ...
                </Colour>
            </Video>
            <Audio>
                ...
            </Audio>
        </TrackEntry>
    </Tracks>
    <Cues>
        <CuePoint>
            <CueTrackPositions>...</CueTrackPositions>
        </CuePoint>
    </Cues>
    <Cluster>
        <Timecode>...</Timecode>
        <SimpleBlock>...</SimpleBlock>
        <SimpleBlock>...</SimpleBlock>
        <SimpleBlock>...</SimpleBlock>
        <SimpleBlock>...</SimpleBlock>
        ...
    </Cluster>
    <Cluster>
        <Timecode>...</Timecode>
        <SimpleBlock>...</SimpleBlock>
        <SimpleBlock>...</SimpleBlock>
        <SimpleBlock>...</SimpleBlock>
        <SimpleBlock>...</SimpleBlock>
        ...
    </Cluster>
    ...
</Segment>
```

The way I was reading the data, the first block contained all of the header information (EBML data, segment data, tracks, timecode, etc) and all later chunks were just a stream of `<Cluster>` and `<SimpleBlock>` tags (with an odd `<Timecode>` every now and then)

Ultimately what I had to do was build a rudimentary demuxer to parse through the EBML file and extract the header information. Then whenever I performed a seek, this header information was injected into the buffer before any video data.

### My Advice

Don't bother. MSE is terrible and this was a 72 hour nightmare. Save yourself the headache.

Comment: As someone who also went through this nightmare awhile back, I'm sorry I didn't stumble across this earlier.  Excellent notes.  :-)  If you end up working on this again, there are a few NPM packages for parsing out clusters and such from Mastroska/WebM, making it pretty easy to write these chunks back in via MSE in whatever order you need.  Also, there are a few outstanding bugs in Chromium that make this all very difficult due to timestamps... I'll link back here if I can find those again.